# Having problem with my websites nav bar redirect button

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Video:
https://youtu.be/aOtayR8LOuc

Essential when I click a button on my nav it will go there but since I have the same nav bar on each page it will try to go to pages/about even if im already there (ex. pages/about/pages/about)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>FFA Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        
        <div class="topnav">
      <a class="active" href="">Home</a>
      <a href="pages/News">News</a>
      <a href="pages/Animals">Animals</a>
      <a href="pages/About">About Me</a>
      <a href="pages/Credits">Credits</a>
    </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
        .topnav {
          background-color: #333;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
        .topnav a {
          float: left;
          color: #f2f2f2;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 17px;
        }
        
        /* Change the color of links on hover */
        .topnav a:hover {
          background-color: #ddd;
          color: black;
        }
        
        /* Add a color to the active/current link */
        .topnav a.active {
          background-color: #04AA6D;
          color: white;
        }
```

Comment: could you provide your relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your HTML code like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>FFA Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a class="active" href="">Home</a>
            <a href="/pages/News">News</a>
            <a href="/pages/Animals">Animals</a>
            <a href="/pages/About">About Me</a>
            <a href="/pages/Credits">Credits</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not working as you expected because you provided false paths since the `pages` files are in a different folder not the parent so here is what you need to do

for the `index.html`:

```
<body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="/src/index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="pages/News.html">News</a>
    <a href="pages/Animals.html">Animals</a>
    <a href="pages/About.html">About Me</a>
    <a href="pages/Credits.html">Credits</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

for any other page inside the pages folder for example `News.html`:

```
<body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="../index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="News.html">News</a>
        <a href="Animals.html">Animals</a>
        <a href="About.html">About Me</a>
        <a href="Credits.html">Credits</a>
    </div>
    <h1>News</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: @CompanionCubeGD great! It would be nice if you accept my answer since the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Well there seems no issues with your `index.html` file except missing the `.html` extension after each page name, and you just need to fix the redirection in the `pages/News , pages/Animals , pages/About, pages/Credits` html files, as when you click on any one of them you are no longer in the `root` of your project instead you are inside `pages/` so the redirection changes.

so your other pages(About/Credits/Animals/News) should look like this.
make whatever page you wish to make active.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>FFA Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="../app.js"></script>
        
        <div class="topnav">
      <a class="active" href="">Home</a>
      <a href="News.html">News</a>
      <a href="Animals.html">Animals</a>
      <a href="About.html">About Me</a>
      <a href="Credits.html">Credits</a>
    </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try adding "../" before the path? So `<a href="../pages/News">News</a>` ...
Maybe this works?